# How do I output from a (doubly) recursive function?

Tags: r, recursion

How do I get the output of this function in R?

```r
nodes2 <- c(1,2,4,5,10,11,20,21)
getLeftOrder <- function(root, snodes, nodes) {
  if ( length(nodes) == 0 ) {
    return(snodes)
  } else {
    nodes <- nodes[-(which(nodes == (2*root)))]
    getLeftOrder(2*root, snodes, nodes)
    snodes <- c(snodes, root)
    cat(root, fill = TRUE)
    nodes <- nodes[-(which(nodes == (2*root+1)))]
    getLeftOrder(2*root+1, snodes, nodes)
  }
}
tnodes <- getLeftOrder(1, vector('integer'), nodes2)
```

The in-order traversal/reordering output from `cat()` is fine but the output in `tnodes` is not. I would like to avoid using `<<-` operator.

Comment: What do you want it to return? The non-recursing clause returns `vector('integer')`, and you don't have anything to return something more interesting or collect returns. Let's take a step back: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to return the output that is being produced by `cat` in the vector snodes. In particular, in the order that it is being produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs to [at least sometimes] return something interesting, and collect results as recursive calls return. Trying to keep the current logic the same, you want the roots from the first set of recursive calls, the current root, and the roots from the second set of recursive calls. Adding in some `message()` calls so we can see what's happening:

```r
nodes2 <- c(1,2,4,5,10,11,20,21)

getLeftOrder <- function(root, nodes) {
    message('root: ', root, '  nodes: ', paste(nodes, collapse = ' '))
    if ( length(nodes) == 0 ) {
        return(NULL)
    } else {
        nodes <- nodes[-which(nodes == 2*root)]
        r1 <- getLeftOrder(2*root, nodes)
        message(root)
        nodes <- nodes[-which(nodes == 2*root + 1)]
        r2 <- getLeftOrder(2*root+1, nodes)
        return(c(r1, root, r2))
    }
}
```

which runs like so:

```r
tnodes <- getLeftOrder(1, nodes2)
#> root: 1  nodes: 1 2 4 5 10 11 20 21
#> root: 2  nodes: 1 4 5 10 11 20 21
#> root: 4  nodes: 1 5 10 11 20 21
#> root: 8  nodes:
#> 4
#> root: 9  nodes:
#> 2
#> root: 5  nodes: 1 10 11 20 21
#> root: 10  nodes: 1 11 20 21
#> root: 20  nodes: 1 11 21
#> root: 40  nodes:
#> 20
#> root: 41  nodes:
#> 10
#> root: 21  nodes: 1 11
#> root: 42  nodes:
#> 21
#> root: 43  nodes:
#> 5
#> root: 11  nodes: 1 20 21
#> root: 22  nodes:
#> 11
#> root: 23  nodes:
#> 1
#> root: 3  nodes:

tnodes
#> [1]  4  2 20 10 21  5 11  1
```

I still don't quite understand the logic here, though; there's quite likely a simpler way to do this.

Comment: If there is a simpler way to do it I would love to know. My original intention was to go from a level ordering of binary nodes: `nodes2` above, to an infix ordering as you have produced.