# Change order of vector of nodes from level order to infix order in r

Tags: r

I have a vector of nodes taken from a binary regression tree. These are in level order, for example, `1,2,4,5,10,11`. I would like to place them in infix order like so: `4,2,10,5,11,1`. Thanks to Alistaire I have [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641157/how-do-i-output-from-a-doubly-recursive-function) that uses recursion. But as they point out, "There has to be a better way". I was hoping someone might be able to help me out with a non-recursive approach. The recursive version is very slow for vectors of any reasonable length. I have also tried creating a binary tree using igraph and data.tree but I cannot seem to get the ordering I want from these.

Comment: What is the logic? How are you deciding on the positioning??

Comment: No that does not explain the logic. Even Allister claims he does not understand the logic. Read through his answer. They just copied your code and added the return value.

Comment: Could you explain as to how 1 goest to the end? 4 becomes the forst one etc??. Explain it without the code

Comment: Simply put. What made you write the code the way you did? What were you trying to accomplish? What is the reasoning behind the code?

Comment: The reasoning is stated in the question? The way is written, if I am not mistaken, which I probably am, is so that I can first search left then right returning at each step. I thought this was a basic infix -reordering?

Comment: [see](https://users.monash.edu/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Recn/Binary/) at the bottom of the page, under binary trees, infix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this without recursion since you are dealing with a binary tree, which has a fixed structure like the following tree with depth 5:
[image]

Suppose we have a vector of your nodes:

```r
nodes <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11)
```

First of all, we only want a binary tree that is of a suitable depth to accommodate your largest node. We can get the required depth by doing:

```r
depth <- ceiling(log(max(nodes), 2))
```

And a data frame that gives the node number, depth and 'leftness' of a sufficiently large binary tree like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(node = seq(2^(depth) - 1),
                 depth = rep(seq(depth), times = 2^(seq(depth) - 1)),
                 leftness = unlist(sapply(2^seq(depth) - 1, 
                      function(x) (seq(x)[seq(x) %% 2 ==1])/(x + 1))))
```

However, we only need the subset of this tree that matches your nodes:

```r
df <- df[match(nodes, df$node),]

df
#>    node depth leftness
#> 1     1     1   0.5000
#> 2     2     2   0.2500
#> 4     4     3   0.1250
#> 5     5     3   0.3750
#> 10   10     4   0.3125
#> 11   11     4   0.4375
```

And we can sort the nodes in order according to leftness:

```r
df$node[order(df$leftness)]
#> [1]  4  2 10  5 11  1
```

Which is your expected result.

To generalize this, just put the above steps in a function:

```r
sort_left <- function(nodes) {
  depth <- ceiling(log(max(nodes), 2))

  df <- data.frame(node = seq(2^(depth) - 1),
                   depth = rep(seq(depth), times = 2^(seq(depth) - 1)),
                   leftness = unlist(sapply(2^seq(depth) - 1, 
                      function(x) (seq(x)[seq(x) %% 2 ==1])/(x + 1))))

  df <- df[match(nodes, df$node),]
  df$node[order(df$leftness)]
}
```

So we can do:

```r
sort_left( c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11))
#> [1]  4  2 10  5 11  1
```

Or, given the example in your original question,

```r
sort_left(c(1,2,4,5,10,11,20,21))
#> [1]  4  2 20 10 21  5 11  1
```

Which was the desired result. All without recursion.